# Add 0.75x playback speed on React Native JW Media Player package

Tags: android, ios, react-native, jwplayer

Developed a react native streaming app, and used JW Player as the video player. I don't see a way using react native jw media player to add a new playback speed of 0.75x, but we have multiple requests to provide this speed. In the JW Player website I can edit the json of the app player to allow 0.75x, but on our app I don't see a way in the RNJWMP package to add this.

Answer (score 0):

RNJWMP did not have capability to do this directly, so the solution for us was to go into native code and add the functionality to support 0.75x speed

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include the code you were able to use to accomplish this? That might help future members of the community with a similar problem.